# ffmpeg to cut intro and replace with new intro

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to cut out the intro in my video and replace it with a new intro. I run into a buffer underflow error when I try this. The commands I'm using are:

```
ffmpeg -i LegalFinancialPlanning.mpg -ss 00:00:05.8 -c copy legalcut.mpg    
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy legalfinal.mpg
```

I am able to cut the video, however it does not concatenate properly. The error I get is:

```
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=5673 size=11229
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=7697 size=11229
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=7697 size=11229
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=9721 size=11229
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=9721 size=11229
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=511 size=1957
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=573 size=2633
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=2597 size=2633
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=2597 size=2633
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1983 size=11161
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=4007 size=11161
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=4007 size=11161
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=6031 size=11161
[vob @ 0x7fd08c058200] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
```

Eventually I want to write a bash script so I can replace the intro/outro in multiple videos at once, which is why I'm using ffmpeg. Does anyone have insight on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post stream info for both files. You can get that by running 'ffprobe -i filename.ext'. It also appears near the top of the ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from each command. You can of course trim repeating lines.